# Image Processing techniques DFT or Thresholding

Tags: python, opencv, dft, image-thresholding

I am a beginner in image processing. I started with opencv . Now there is a fundamental confusion to me . One is thresholding and one is image transformation . I am confused in these two parts.Till now i have understood couple of things:
1. Input image has to converted into Grayscale.
2. After that have to remove noise.
    2.1 Now to remove noise what should i use thresholding or DFT techniques, when i read , both of them are used to remove noises.

Is my understanding right?
Please guide me .

Thanks

Comment: What is your desired output? What will come next after noise removal?

Comment: I have just started stuck in the concepts .

Comment: Well you can do a lot of work on an image and the noise filtering solution will depend o the image. Moreover, you can also do threshold-like in color space. For instance, you can convert to HSV color space, and then apply a mask that will take HSV_lower_boundaries and HSV_Higher_boudaries to apply a threshold. So even the Grayscale conversion isn't an obligation. It depends of what you want to do.

Comment: i have form image , trying to extract text out of it .So not able to go the next step after filteration and noise reduction .